# Low precision and clamping when writing to floating point FBO

Tags: opengl

I have an FBO which has been created in the following way:

```
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_depthStencilBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_depthStencilBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, m_width, m_height);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, m_texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, GL_RGBA32F_ARB, m_width, m_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_frameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_frameBuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, m_texture, 0);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_depthStencilBuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_depthStencilBuffer);
assert(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE == glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
assert(GL_NO_ERROR == glGetError());
```

I then render to this with this minimal fragment program:

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = float4(3.001001f, 2.00002f, 7.00003f, 4.00004f);
}
```

If I read out the pixels like this:

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, &pixels[0]);
```

and check the pixels written by the above fragment program they are (1, 1, 1, 1). I only added the `glReadPixels` for testing purposes, I get the same problem if I try to sample the FBO in another fragment program with `textureRect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was a stupid bug on my part, in my FBO resize code I called:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, GL_RGBA, ...);
```

instead of

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, GL_RGBA32F_ARB, ...);
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will be clamped to the range (0, 1) - check out [glClampColor](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClampColor.xhtml) and disable color clamping.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It shouldn't apply for sampling a floating point texture, though (as mentioned by the OP).

Comment: It applies to glReadPixels AFAIK. So while the results may not be clamped on the GPU they may be getting clamped on read. From the documentation

"glClampColor controls color clamping that is performed during glReadPixels.target must be GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR. If clamp is GL_TRUE, read color clamping is enabled; if clamp is GL_FALSE, read color clamping is disabled. If clamp is GL_FIXED_ONLY, read color clamping is enabled only if the selected read buffer has fixed point components and disabled otherwise."

Comment: Seems like I may need glClampColor(GL_CLAMP_FRAGMENT_COLOR, GL_FALSE); for the shader to work.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck For the fragment color, the default should actually be `GL_FIXED_ONLY`, but it is a try.

Comment: glClampColor Link is dead