# Texture values clipped to the range 0-1?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

SIMPLE QUESTION:

Does OpenGL clip texture values to the range 0-1 by default? And if it does is there a way to disable this?

DETAILED QUESTION:

I have a texture which, when created, I put some default values in.

I create the texture of RGBA values size 16x16 like this:

```
//Generate the texture and get its ID
GLuint texID;
glGenTextures(1, &texID);

//Bind the texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);

//Define the size of the texture
int width = 16;
int height = 16;
int numberOfElementsPerTexel = 4;
int size = width * height * numberOfElementsPerTexel;

//Create an empty array of texel data
float data[size];
std::fill_n(data, size, 0.0f);

//Add the empty data to the texture
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);
```

To test this works correctly after I create and fill the texture I inspect the contents like this:

```
//Bind the texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);

//Get the data from the texture
float texData[size];
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, texData);
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Value at %d: %f\n", i, texData[i]);
    }
}
```

So this gives a load of 0's as I would expect, then as another test before I call glTexImage2D I modify one of the values in the array of data:

```
data[0] = 1.0f;
```

And as expected this adds a 1.0 in the first number to be printed out. Any number between 0 and 1 prints out as expected however any number greater than 1 or less than 0 clips to that range?

This sounds like it could be because the texture stores colour values and therefore clips to the range of RGBA values. Is this the case or am I doing something wrong?

And if this is the case is there a way to disable it? I'm looking to store arbitrary data in the texture not colour values its just I'm looking to improve performance because the texture/texture lookup structure is highly optimised in the GPU

Comment: Tried to read GL_UNSIGNED_INT instead of GL_FLOAT?

Comment: Are you saying I have done this or are you suggesting I do it? I want to store floats in the texture

Comment: Ah right. Maybe you can use [glClampColor](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glClampColor.xml) like mentioned in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211698/framebuffer-object-with-float-texture-clamps-values)?

Comment: Are you checking the correct array? It seems like you are checking `data`, when you should check `texData`. That would make the problem even more strange however.

Comment: You should change your texture to a unnormalized format like GL_RGBA32F .

Comment: Ebbs no sorry that's just a typo I'll change it :)

Comment: That sounds good Michael which arguments do I need to change? One of the ones in glTexImage2D?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does OpenGL clip texture values to the range 0-1 by default?

Sometimes - depending on the way you are accessing the texture and the texture's *internal format*.

> And if it does is there a way to disable this?

Not really, but you can change the internal format to get what you want.

GL Spec 4.6, Section 2.3.5 Fixed-Point Data Conversions:

> When generic vertex attributes and pixel color or depth components are
>   repre- sented as integers, they are often (but not always) considered
>   to be normalized. Normalized integer values are treated specially when
>   being converted to and from floating-point values, and are usually
>   referred to as normalized fixed-point. Such values are always either
>   signed or unsigned.
>
> ...
>
> The conversion from a floating-point value f to the corresponding
>   unsigned nor- malized fixed-point value c is defined by first **clamping
>   f to the range [0, 1]**, then

The following call is deceiving as `GL_FLOAT` is given for the texture format (which just says the data you give it is 32 bit floating point). The internal format is `GL_RGBA`. I believe most implementations end up using essentially GL_RGBA8 to store this, i.e. 8 bits per channel like `unsigned char r, g, b, a` (although this is not required by the spec). From the above section of the GL spec, the input data values values will be clamped and then converted and to fixed point. 0.0f and below becomes 0 and 1.0f and above becomes 255.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);
```

The same happens when you read and write with such textures in a shader. The integer values get transparently scaled to the [0, 1] range. In your case, reaing with `glGetTexImage` + `GL_FLOAT` also scales the integer values to back down to [0, 1] but the data you passed in has already been clamped. If instead you read with `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` and an `unsigned char`/`GLubyte` array, you should see 0 to 255. When accessing textures it's probably faster to access it with the same format as the internal format. Then there's no need for a conversion.

```
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, texData);
```

In short, **yes, anything outside the range 0 to 1 gets clamped** (eg. using an FBO to write to a typical RGB/A texture). If you don't need the precision but still want numbers bigger than 1 you could scale the values beforehand.

If you need more precision you could use `GL_RGBA32F`, as below. In this case no conversion is required - your input is the same as the texture storage and **clamping does not happen**. The downside is it would take up 4 times as much data, which means 4 times as much to transfer when accessing. Of course this isn't just more *regular* precision because you get the exponent representation in the floating point format.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);
```

Comment: Hi @jozxyqk, could you provide a reference in the OpenGL documentation where it says a `GL_RGBA32F` texture is not clamped? I couldn't find it... Thanks!

Comment: @SamuelLi Section 8.4.4.3 of the gl 4.6 core spec references 2.3.5.1
*Conversion from Normalized Fixed-Point to Floating-Point*. So to be more accurate it's that floating point textures do not need any conversion because they're already floats, but when you convert a fixed point texture, e.g. GL_RGBA8, it clamps and scales any floaitng point values to the range 0 to 1. I updated the answer.

Comment: @jozxyqk Thanks for the clarification. I was reading GLSL specs version 4.1 and it wasn't very clear. This is a little obscure, but is it true that OpenGL does not perform any clamping on floating point values, no matter it's 32bit, 16bit, or 64bit representations?

Comment: @SamuelLi it doesn't look like it and in practice I don't see clamping when reading/writing to floating point textures.

Comment: Thank you @jozxyqk, you are super helpful!