# opengl texture format for floating-point gpgpu

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, gpgpu

I wish to process an image using glsl. For instance - for each pixel, output its squared value: 
(r,g,b)-->(r^2,g^2,b^2). Then I want to read the result into cpu memory using glReadPixels.

This should be simple. However, most glsl examples that I find explain about shaders for image post-processing; thus, their output value already lies in [0,255]. In my example, however, I want to get output values in the range [0^2,255^2]; and I don't want them normalized to [0,255].

The main parts of my code are (after some trials and permutations):

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, data_float);
```

I don't post my entire code since I think these two lines is where my problem lies.

### Edit

Following @Arttu's suggestion, and following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950743/low-precision-and-clamping-when-writing-to-floating-point-fbo) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211698/framebuffer-object-with-float-texture-clamps-values) my code now reads as follows:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, GL_RGBA32F_ARB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, data_float);
```

Still, this does not solve my problem. If I understand correctly - no matter what, my input values get scaled to [0,1] when I insert them. It's up to me to multiply later by 255 or by 255^2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using floating-point texture format will keep your values intact without clamping them to any specific range (in this case, within the limits of 16-bit float representation, of course). You didn't specify your OpenGL version, so this assumes 4.3.

You seem to have conflicting *format* and *internalformat*. You're specifying internalformat `RGBA16F`, but format `BGR`, without the alpha component ([glTexImage2D man page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)). Try the following:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data_float);
```

On the first line you're specifying a 2D texture with four-component, 16-bit floating point format, and OpenGL will expect the texture data to be in BGRA format. Since you have 0 as the last parameter, you're not specifying any image data. Remember that RGBA16F format gives you `half` values in your shader, which will be implicitly casted to 32-bit format if you're assigning the values to `float` or `vec*` variables.

On the second line, you're downloading image data from the device to `data_float`, this time in RGBA order.

If this doesn't solve your problem, you'll probably need to include some more code. Also, adding `glGetError` calls into your code will help you find the call that causes an error. Good luck :)

Comment: thanks for the reply. However, I'm not sure you have to read rgba, but you can also read rgb. Still, the normalization is the things that bothers me. See related posts in my edited questions.

Comment: Did you disable `glClampColor` for read, vertex and fragment targets as instructed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11296152/1629346)?

Comment: Also, you could try with `GL_RGBA32F` in case there's some driver bug relating to the 16F format.